# html5 audio, audio stops by site change

Tags: jquery, ajax, audio, content-management-system

I use a html5 audio tag for background-music in a website (html5) which is build with an CMS called CMS Made Simple (Smarty, jQuery):

```
<div id="audio">

<div style="width:150px;height:15px;margin:0;padding:0;">
<div style="width:57px;float:left;">
<a href="javascript:;" id="play" onclick="document.getElementById('andytimm').play()" title="Play"><img src="images/audio_play.png" width="" height="" alt="Play"></a>
</div>
<div style="width:50px;float:left;">
<a href="javascript:;" id="pause" onclick="document.getElementById('andytimm').pause()" title="Pause"><img src="images/audio_pause.png" width="" height="" alt="Pause"></a>
</div>
<div style="width:36px;float:left;">
<a href="javascript:;" id="stop" onclick="document.getElementById('andytimm').pause(); document.getElementById('andytimm').currentTime = 0;" title="Stop"><img src="images/audio_stop.png" width="" height="" alt="Stop"></a>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>

  <audio id="andytimm">
    <source src="mysong.mp3">
    <source src="mysong.ogg">
  </audio>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>

  <object id="andytimmObj" type="audio/x-mpeg" data="mysong.mp3" autoplay="false" height="45">
    <param name="src" value="mysong.mp3">
    <param name="controller" value="false">
    <param name="autoplay" value="false">
    <param name="autostart" value="0">
  </object>

  <script>
    document.getElementById('play').onclick = function() { document.getElementById('andytimmObj').play() };
    document.getElementById('pause').onclick = function() { document.getElementById('andytimmObj').pause() };
    document.getElementById('stop').onclick = function() { document.getElementById('andytimmObj').stop() };
  </script>

<![endif]-->

</div>
```

Sound works fine.

Whats not that fine, is, that the music stops when I change a site, maybe from "Services" to "Contact" or any other. Is there any way that the music will continue playing, even if sites are changed? I'm not a programmer, therefore it's hard for me to find a solution.

Comment: Do you mean 'pages' rather than 'site'? As in, people clicking links (and staying on your own site) stops the music? If so, this is because the audio is attached to the page, therefore when the page is unloaded, so is the music. To avoid this, use an invisible frame and put the music in there. Lastly, but most importantly, PLEASE DON'T PUT MUSIC ON A WEBSITE. Especially not auto-playing music. This is not 1997.